# Pass by Reference - Char Array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//helper function
int arguments(char filename [100], int argc , char ** argv )
{
    int ret = (argc < 3) ? -1 : 1;
    filename =  argv[1];
    return ret;
}
int main (int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char * filename;
    FILE *fp;
    //fill the empty bucket in other function
    int ret = arguments(filename, argc , argv);

    if(ret == -1)
    {
        perror("Error, something occured.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("The file is called %s\n",filename);
    return 0;
}
```

I am simply trying to change the name of the argv[1] to the name of what they give. But
it does not work in the function arguments(), I just to read it and see that it is correctly reading in argv[1], i think i am doing it right

Comment: Then pass `filename` by "reference" (ie. by a pointer to it) - `&filename`.

Comment: @KamilCuk as in arguments(&filename, argc, argv); because I did that and it says, warning: passing argument 1 of ‘arguments’ from incompatible pointer type...

Comment: @KamilCuk, never mind it worked what you said!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `filename` as a *pointer to pointer* to `char`, like so:

```
int arguments(char **filename, int argc , char ** argv )
{
  int ret = (argc < 3) ? -1 : 1;
  *filename =  argv[1]; // char * = char * 
  return ret;
}
```

then call it as

```
/**
 * type of filename is char *, so type of &filename is char **
 */
int ret = arguments(&filename, argc , argv);
```

Remember, for a function to change the value of an input parameter such that the change is reflected in the calling function, you must pass a pointer to that parameter:

```
void foo( T *ptr ) // for any type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value();  // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T val;
  foo( &val ); // update the value in val
}
```

This is true for pointer types as well - if we replace `T` with `P *`, we get:

```
void foo( P **ptr ) // for any type T
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value();  // write a new pointer value to the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *val;
  foo( &val ); // update the pointer value in val
}
```

All we've done is replace the type `T` with the type `P *`, but everything else is the same.  You still need to use `&val` when you pass the argument, which means the formal parameter `ptr` will have one more level of indirection than `val`, and you must use `*ptr` to assign the new value.